# spring integration router unresolved channel id

Tags: spring-integration

I've read the documentation but I've not found what I'm looking for, which is:
Is there a way to have in the MessageDeliveryException thrown by a router defined like this (if it can't resolve a channel from the payload):

```
<int:payload-type-router input-channel="exceptionIntegrationGatewayInbound"
        resolution-required="true" id="typePayloadRouterError">
        <int:mapping type="package.class"
            channel="channelDest" />
</int:payload-type-router>
```

the ID specified in the router's definition? (e.g. **typePayloadRouterError**).
Much like what happens when a filter rejects a message when it's defined like below:

```
<int:filter expression="(payload.operationResult?.equals('0')?:false)"
            throw-exception-on-rejection="true" />
```

Am I asking for something already implemented or something not useful? (It would really help the debugging/find where it broke if someone didn't put meaningful logs through the message chain).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are right. There is no such an info in the related code. It looks only like this (`AbstractMessageRouter`):

```
else {
    throw new MessageDeliveryException(message,
        "no channel resolved by router and no default output channel defined");
}
```

Where something similar from `MessageFilter` is:

```
if (this.throwExceptionOnRejection) {
    throw new MessageRejectedException(message, "MessageFilter '" + this.getComponentName()
            + "' rejected Message");
}
```

So, I guess you feel free to raise a [JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT) issue on the matter.

And it would be great if you'll provide the [contribution](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md)!

BTW: what is bad here, there is no any workaround to overcome your requirements.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.
I'll raise a JIRA/try to come up with a contribution.
Next time, I should look more on the code and less on StackOverflow: helps the problem solving skills!.

Comment: raised Jira at https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3563.
I'll try to make a pull request this evening

Comment: Good. Thanks. +1 to you for that ;-)

Comment: Hey @Artem, sorry to bother you again.
I'm still new to github and big projects merge propagation, maven releases etc.
I was just wondering how to read your JIRA resolution.
The simplest of all question would be: how can I enjoy the benefits of this change? Since I'm using 4.0.4.RELEASE Spring Integration, should I switch to SNAPSHOT?

Comment: @Massimo, right now you just need to upgrade to 4.0.6. We released it yesterday with this fix!